# Can i use iOS 7.0 as deployment target for iOS 7.0.3

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode 6.1 the minimum iOS version i can install is iOS 7.0.3. In Xcode 6.1 deployments target i can put iOS 6.1, 7.0, 7.1 and so on. Since i made my app for iOS 7.0.3 as well as all above ios's, can i put a deployment target of iOS 7.0 to support the iOS 7.0.3?

Comment: You can deploy to any version less than or equal to your intended support (7.0.3).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

Deployment target specify the minimum supported iOS version.
If you put iOS 7.0 it will support all iOS version's above 7.0 including 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do. Deployment Target refers to the minimum ios version to be supported for the app. So if you use deployment target as 7.0, it will work for all the versions from 7.0 to latest

Comment: I understand that part. But I never worked on iOS 7 simulator. The earliest iOS version I worker on is iOS 7.0.3. So if someone uses my app and they have iOS 7.0 will they see some glitchy or buggy or weirdly affected app as opposed to what I actually worked on iOS 7.0.3 and higher?

Comment: @Mika: Have anyone tried your app and they had any problem?

Comment: The app hasn't been tested yet on an actual device if that's what you mean.